Trying to work with the ComsosDb Change Feed Reader on an Azure function, how do I define the StartFromTime parameter?
I have an Azure Function that looks like this:
[Function("MyCosmosDBTrigger")]
public async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
    databaseName: "myDatabase",
    containerName: "myContainer",
    Connection = "myConnection",
    LeaseContainerName = "leases",
    CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true,
    StartFromBeginning = false,
    MaxItemsPerInvocation = 1000

    //StartFromTime = "2024-04-16T10:30:27Z"
    )] IReadOnlyList<JsonElement> input)
{
...
}

This trigger is new and is a work-in-progress.  So far, this works.  However, before we can finish this and publish it to production, I need to set the StartFromTime parameter. Specifically, we will want to execute this method from about a month ago.  We have snap-shot data and it will be added to the database.  In short, this process is replacing the nightly-snapshot process so that real-time data can be added to a reporting server.  The reason why we'll start it from, say, a "month previous" is just to check results, while having a reasonable amount of data inputted into the reports table from this new process.
Regardless of the time-frame, I cannot get this method to work with the StartFromTime parameter. Specifically, the local function runtime has an issue with it's definition and can't seem to serialize it to whatever format it wants to use.  When I run the function above, but uncomment out the StartFromTime parameter, I get a local error:

The listener for function 'Functions.MyCosmosDBTrigger' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client: StartTime cannot have DateTimeKind.Unspecified (Parameter 'value').

How can I fix this?  The time text appears to be correct, especially based off of the limited definition on the property within the disassembled code.  What am I doing wrong here?

The datetime format you have should work fine and not be treated as DateTimeKind.Unspecified https://i.sstatic.net/UDpxaz5E.png . I did recently encounter an issue where when pulling the value from app settings it was changing the format from yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy and then throwing that error but I've never had any problems with hardcoded values in this attribute - I have always used the format 2024-05-18T00:00:00.000Z (with milliseconds present)

By the way just in case the issue you are seeing is somehow related to the behaviour I was seeing when using the app settings interpolation it looked like adding a leading space to the value was sufficient to work around it. My assumption was that somewhere in the function apps they are using Newtonsoft.Json and getting bitten by this mis feature.  https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862  the leading space prevented the format being changed from yyyy-mm-dd to dd/mm/yyyy but still parses OK with DateTime.Parse

Also are you using the most up-to-date version of the CosmosDB extension? There was a related fix to this quite a long time ago  https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/pull/3645
